# How do I solve for $k$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Question**: If $$\frac{d^3x}{dy^3}+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-4}-k\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-5}\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)^2=0$$
Is an identity , Then $k=?$

All I need is the method on how to convert this $\frac{d^3x}{dy^3}$ to a form which is common to these $\frac{dy}{dx}$ terms.

Will doing $\displaystyle\frac{d(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2})}{dx}$ Do the job?
Please guide.

Comment: What is $y$? Can you quote the original question?

Comment: This is the point. There is no $y$ @DHMO

Comment: I guess this is an inverse function problem.  Every calculus student learns to compute $dx/dy$ in terms of $dy/dx$.  Presumably this book went on to express $d^2 x/dy^2$ in terms of the derivative and second derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$.  Then asks the student this question, which is the third derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$, $\frac{d^2 x}{dy^2} = \frac{d}{dy}\left[\frac{dx}{dy}\right] = \frac{d}{dy}\left[\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}\right]$. Using quotient rule, we get $-\frac{\frac{d}{dy}\left[\frac{dy}{dx}\right]}{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}$. From implicit differentiation, we know $\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{d}{dy}$, this is just the rule that means you take the derivative w.r.t $y$ then multiply $y^\prime$. Solving for $\frac{d}{dy}$ and substituting gives $-\frac{\frac{dx}{dy}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{dy}{dx}\right]}{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} = -\frac{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3} = \frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$.

Now, $\frac{d^3x}{dy^3} = \frac{d}{dy}\left[\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}\right] = \frac{d}{dy}\left[-\frac{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3} \right]$. Approach the same way with quotient rule and you should get what you're looking for.

Comment: Does this method gives the answer as 3?